# How to properly structure multiple user types?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

So i'm building a database for an app/website. It's essentially a e-commerce marketplace/platform where a brand can sign up to upload their products and customers can also then sign up to purchase any products from any various brands.

A brand and or employee cannot be a customer

A customer cannot be a brand

This is the structure I have so far, but it seems to me that from this diagram it implies that a user can be a customer, brand and brand employee at the same time.

Is there a better optimal structure for this?

[image]

Comment: Can several `customer`/`brand`/`brand_employee` be associated with a single `user`? By the way, don't use reserved SQL key words like `user` for table names.

Comment: Noted thanks. No a single customer can only be associated with a single user. Same with the brand and brand employee. So one customer to one user, one brand to one user, one brand employee to one user.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn around the foreign key relationships and add three foreign keys to `user`, one for each of `customer`, `brand` and `brand_employee`. Then add a `CHECK` constraint that makes sure that exactly one of the foreign keys is `NOT NULL`:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
   id                uuid PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
   customer_id       uuid REFERENCES customer(id),
   brand_id          uuid REFERENCES brand(id),
   brand_employee_id uuid REFERENCES brand_employee(id),
   CHECK (customer_id IS NOT NULL AND brand_id IS     NULL AND brand_employee_id IS     NULL OR
          customer_id IS     NULL AND brand_id IS NOT NULL AND brand_employee_id IS     NULL OR
          customer_id IS     NULL AND brand_id IS     NULL AND brand_employee_id IS NOT NULL)
);
```

Comment: Could you show me visually? also Isn't it bad to have a many NOT NULL fields?

Comment: Is there a better way? maybe adding userTypes table? with a type field of either `customer`, `brand` or `brand_employee`? just not sure how to associate a user to one of the three tables

Comment: I added an example. By the way, *never* model UUIDs as `varchar` (always use the appropriate data type). It is *good* to have as many NOT NULL columns as possible, because that improves data quality and makes your queries simpler and faster.